# Extending a parent and using parent render method react native

Tags: react-native, extending-classes

This is a general question as I've not seen anything like this anywhere.
So if I have a parent component like the examples below and I was to render the children of the child in the parent how could I do this if its possible (other than making a getParentComponent(children) method in the parent).
Is there a was that when the child render gets called that the child content automatically gets inserted?

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {View} from 'react--native;

class CustomView extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styels.customStyle}>
                // this is where I want to render my child content
            </View>
        )
    }
}

import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {CustomView} from 'somewhere;

class ChildView extends CustomView {
    render() {
        return (
            <View style={styels.childStyle}>
                // take this view and all the content with in and render it in the parent render
            </View>
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By nature, a parent class has no knowledge of any class that `extends` it. So, no. [MDN extends documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Classes/extends) explains more.

Otherwise, [refs](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/more-about-refs.html) might help you get access to a `Component`'s `props`, like `children`.

Comment: Thank you very much. Ill have a go at coming up with some sort of solution and i will repost in my answer. But I checked the documentation you sent and you are right. Thank you